# Can I use cross site publishing on author sites that are not site collections?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, cross-site-publishing

I have multiple sites that publish data that I need to be collected to one site (n:1). But the "n" author sites are not site collections so I cannot "turn on" the cross-site publishing feature on those sites.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately No! the publishing content sites should be site collections.

**Note:**

- In a cross-site collection publishing scenario, you must have at least two **site collections**, one for `authoring content` and one for `publishing content`.
- Use the `Product Catalog Site Collection template` to create `authoring site collections` because the `Cross-Site Collection Publishing feature` is activated by default.
- To activate the `Cross-Site Collection Publishing feature` , the user must be a site collection administrator on the authoring site collection.